# Find parabola given lines it is differentiable with

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity, conic-sections, tangent-line

I have been given two lines and am asked to connect them with a parabola; the resulting shape needs to be continuous and differentiable (at either point where the parabola meets a line, the instantaneous rates of change need to be the same. The project itself is to "design a rollercoaster track" by getting the formula of the lines/parabola making up the track.)

The parabola is/needs to be in y = ax^2 + bx + c formula. **I need to find a, b, and c.**

So the line on the left, L1, has a slope of 0.7 and meets the parabola at point P, which is at (0, 0)

The line to the right of the parabola, L2, has a a slope of -1.5 and meets the parabola at point Q.

I know point P and point Q are 40 meters apart, so the x value of Q must be 40. I know by the wording of the question that P is higher than Q.

This is my *rough* sketch of the graph, just to put an image to my words. (it's rough so ignore the units of measurement) [Link to image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0G6su.png)

I know about derivatives but I know next to nothing about parabolas. I know my c = 0 because c is the Y intercept and the parabola starts at point P which is the origin. But... I know nothing else. I don't even know where to start. Can I get some hints or something? :(

EDIT: I think I graphed this right with the answer I got and the parabola & the second line don't ever intersect
[image]

Comment: $y'=0.7$ at $x=0$ and $y'=-1.5$ at $x=40$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the general form $y=ax^2+bx+c$, and its derivative, $y'=2ax+b$ with the $(x,y)$ coordinates and slopes at the required points. As stated, you know $c=0$. You must find $a$ and $b$.

Solution assuming that $Q(x_Q,y_Q)$ lies on the circle with radius 40 centered at $P(0,0)$:

$f(x)=ax^2+bx$

$f'(x)=2ax+b$

$P$ lies on the parabola and $m_P=0.7$ so $f'(0)=b=0.7$

Now we have

$f(x)=ax^2+0.7x$

$f'(x)=2ax+0.7$

Q lies on both the parabola and the circle. We also know $m_Q=-1.5$.

(1)   $y_Q=ax_Q^2+0.7x_Q$

(2)   $x_Q^2+y_Q^2=40^2$

(3)   $-1.5=2ax_Q+0.7$

This is a system of three independent equations with three unknowns, $a$, $x_Q$, and $y_Q$. Use substitution to first eliminate $x_Q$ and then again to eliminate $y_Q$. Now you can solve for $a$.

Comment: I plugged in f ' (0) = 0.7 = 2a(0) + b so b = 0.7
And f ' (40) = -1.5 = 2a(40) + 0.7 so a = -0.0275 but I graphed that and it was clearly wrong. I must have misinterpreted instructions? 
What did you mean by "the general" ?

Comment: @IzzieCorley Your solution is fine, check if you graphed it correctly.

Comment: I clarified my answer a bit, but it should like you've got it. Give my solution a check if you agree.

Comment: @IzzieCorley The x of point Q is not 40. Its distance  from P is 40. Q is on a circle with center P and radius 40

Comment: I uploaded a screenshot of my graph plus the input I used on the graphing program. Still not sure what I did wrong. Will try to go over my answers more. (Also @Raffaele the instructions specifically say horizontal distance and I apologize for my unclarity but that'd be the x difference.)

Comment: @IzzieCorley I updated my answer, but now I see that you've decided the Q must horizontally 40 units from P.  In the future, please read the problem carefully and share the exact text of the problem in your question here.

Comment: Something is broken about this problem as stated. If $Q$ is 40 units to the right of $P$, $Q$ must be $(40,0)$.  So $P$ and $Q$ are the roots of the parabola and its vertex occurs at $x=20$.  Using these facts, I find that $a=\frac{-0.7}{40}$ and $b=0.7$ so that $f'(x)=-\frac{0.7}{20}x+0.7$.  Which means that $f'(40)=-0.7$ which is not $-1.5$ it says in the problem.  I've provided a solution above that works if $Q$ is allowed to be in any point 40 units from $P.$

Comment: Figured out what I did wrong. Math was right (a = -0.0275, b = 0.7) but I was graphing it wrong so it didn't look right. Used the wrong formula for L2 haha. Thank you so much for your help! :-)